# React native set state across the component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm using redux & react navigation to manage initial route & screen. My initial screen is splash after that I'm redirect to home screen here I'm getting data from API and I want to set "Login User name" which is define in sidebar, sidebar call in DrawerNavigator.

Comment: I would suggest giving a bit more info about your setup and some code. With the details provided it will be pretty hard for anyone to help out here.

Answer (score 0):

after getting data at homepage call actions to update data in redux like below

```
Class Home extends Component{
 comsponentDidMount(){
  apiCall.then(response =>{
    this.props.updateUser(response.user)        //I am using api returning some user data as user
  });
 }
}
 render(){
  <SomeComponent/>
 }
const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
  return state;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispacth)=>{
  return{
   updateUser:(user)=>dispatch(()=>{type:"UPDATE_USER", user}) //your action creator may look like this
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home); //connect from react-redux
```

within your sidebar get user using redux

```
Class SideBar extends Component{

 render(){
 <View>
{this.props.user ? <UserComponent/>:<UnAuthenticatedUser/>}
</View>
}

}
const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
      return {
        user:state.user      //extract user from state
      };
    }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SideBar);
```

***change data and functions according to your reducers and architecture

[check redux doc](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) for understanding more